# sort listview items from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to sort my listview items from sqlite db.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 final String[] categories = {
        "Firstname", "Lastname", "Last check up"
};

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewallpatients);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
        (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spCategory);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

   }

 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String f = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    switch(position){
    case 0:
        ca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
             public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                 return dbHelper.sortByFirstname(f);
             }
        }); 

        break;
    case 1:
        ca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
             public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                 return dbHelper.sortByLastname(f);
             }
      }); 
        break;
    case 2:
        ca.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
             public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                 return dbHelper.fetchPatientsByName(constraint.toString());
             }
      }); 
        break;
    }
}
```

**DBHelper.class**

```
   public Cursor sortByFirstname(CharSequence inputText) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP },
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP  },
         KEY_FNAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, "FirstName asc", null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

}

public Cursor sortByLastname(CharSequence inputText) throws SQLException {

      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP },
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP  },
         KEY_FNAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, "LastName asc", null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

}
```

Basically, a user can sort the list by choosing from the spinner by firstname, lastname or last check up. I've tried doing the above code to no avail. I don't know what's wrong with the code? Or have I missed something? Any ideas guys? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about executing query directly?
"SELECT " + KEY_ID + "," + KEY_FNAME + "," + KEY_LNAME + "," + KEY_DIAGNOSIS + "," + KEY_LASTFFUP + "FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_FNAME + " LIKE '%" + inputText + "%' ORDER BY " + KEY_FNAME ";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP },
         null, null, null, null, KEY_LNAME + " ASC");
```

More detail [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html)

Comment: make a space like that and then try KEY_LNAME +" "+ "ASC"

Comment: I added space but it's still the same?

Comment: I don't know I think the query is not the problem but the customadapter filter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mCursor = myDataBase.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
               KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP  },
         KEY_FNAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, "FirstName ASC", null);
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: whats the exact problem do you have??

Comment: when i selected from the spinner it was not sorting

Comment: this is the way to get sorting data. print the query in Log and check its right or not??

Comment: this is the query I use: mCursor = myDataBase.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { 
                 KEY_ID, KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_DIAGNOSIS, KEY_LASTFFUP },
           null, null, null, KEY_LNAME + "ASC" , null,);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37851/discussion-between-dunkey-and-armaan-stranger)